# How to bypass MFA using Powershell to upload inSharepoint site

Tags: powershell, office-365

I have created one poweshell script which uploads the data from excel file to office 365 lists. Now I'm facing an issue because of MFA access enabled for my user in office 365 site. Is there any way to bypass the MFA authentication in powershell?

I have wrote the powershell script in client side object model. Script is running from normal pc/laptop (no sharepoint enviroment).

Is it possible to by pass through the web api powershell script? if yes, please provide code block.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using an application password? I dont have a MFA user to test with. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/multi-factor-authentication/multi-factor-authentication-end-user-app-passwords